# Difference between come up and come on up

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

What is the difference between come up and come on up?

I was able to check the meaning of come up here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-up

but could not search for come on up.

Comment: _Come on up_ is simply an encouragement to someone to join the speaker upstairs or on a higher level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Come on up' is a combination of '[come on](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/come-on)' and '[come up](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/come-up)'.

'Come up' is an instruction or request for someone to come in a particular direction (note that 'up' doesn't always mean to travel upwards, vertically - it can also mean to travel in a northerly compass direction).

'Come on' is an encouragement to do something. So, saying "come on up" is an encouragement, but adding the direction.